# trying to write strings line by line into a file

Tags: java, jfilechooser

The following code writes an array into the file, but my problem that it writes it on onto one line when instead I needs it to be on a newline every time that it writes and I can't figure out how to make this part of the code work. I tried adding in the code for a newline as you would for strings but I'm assuming this is not the correct way as it doesn't work.

```
private class SaveButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    { 
      String [] data = dataSource.getList();

      JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
      chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("/home/me/Documents"));
      int retrival = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
      if (retrival == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try {
          FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+".txt");
          for (int i=0; i<data.length ; i++)
          {

            fw.write(data[i] + " \n");
          }
          //fw.write(data.toString());
          fw.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }

      }

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
fw.write(data[i] + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is writing newlines, but it's likely you're viewing the text file with a text editor that doesn't recognize newline by itself (notepad for instance).

Try:

```
fw.write(data[i] + " \r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) to easily print individual lines

```
PrintWriter fw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+".txt"));
for (int i=0; i<data.length ; i++) {
    fw.println(data[i]);
}
fw.close();
```

Note, you should put the `close` in a `finally` as otherwise there can be situations when `close` is not called. In fact you should use the new Java 7 try-with-resources synatx:

```
try(PrintWriter fw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+".txt"))) {
    // stuff
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note that this will output platform specific linebreaks, so `\r\n` on windows and `\n` on Unix. One problem that you will run into time and time again when creating files is opening a file created on one platform on another platform.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+".txt");
```

1. `chooser.getSelectedFile()` should already return a file name with extension so trying adding an extension `".txt"` to it isn't making much sense to me.
2. File writing might be a lengthy operation. So you should run the file writing operation inside a separate thread to avoid blocking `EDT` thread inside which Swing does it's event management and GUI rendering task. Otherwise your application might get *FREEZED*.
3. You might be interested with `FileWriter(File file, boolean append)` to append your data to a existing file.
4. Try using `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to get the correct [newline separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) for your platform.